# Subject line problem when using action "Thank-you Letters for Contributions" in Find Contributions v4.6.8

Tags: civimail, civicontribute

I'm trying to use an email template in the "Thank-you Letters for Contributions" action on the Find Contributions results page - civicrm v4.6.8

This action brings up the form "Create Printabe Letters (PDF)" In this form:
- I select "Send emails where possible. Generate printable PDF’s for contacts who cannot receive email." for the Print and email options.
- I choose an email template with which the civi form correctly fills in the Activity Subject and Your Letter fields.

But no matter what text I put in the Activity Subject field, every email sent has the subject line:  Thank you for your contribution/s

Any ideas for getting the template subject line to appear would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching for solutions before posting this, but but clearly didn't search on the right thing.  Found a jira reference today.  Looks like this was solved last month. Check it out here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17548